# Are the tenses of verb after "was" correct when referring to past event?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I used was because I am referring to a past event, but I'm not sure if the verb form of the verbs see and speak are correct. See my sentence below:

> I **was** so happy seeing my family while I'm speaking on the stage.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Since you're talking about two events that took place in the past, you need two past-tense verbs to describe those actions. As for the verb *see*, it's very common for adjectives in English to be followed by infinitive forms of verbs. So, use *to see*, which is the infinitive of *see*, instead of *seeing*. And there is also no need to use the adverb *so* as it's mostly used as part of the construction *so ... that* (e.g. *I was so happy to see them that I could barely speak.*):

> I **was** happy **to see** my family while I **was speaking** on the stage.